# How to keep an offline Anaconda environment on a server updated properly?

Tags: server, anaconda, package, conda, offline

My goal is to have an **offline anaconda** environment on a server (i.e. without internet connection) which is up-to-date with my **local anaconda** (with internet connection).
To initially set up my **offline anaconda** I have conda-packed my **local anaconda** environment, transferred it to the server via scp and activated the environment there.

However, when I now *install new packages* to my **local anaconda** and want to keep my **offline anaconda** up-to-date with it, do I need to

1. conda-pack the whole environment again or
2. can I create e.g. a tar.bz2 file from the current environment revision and do only an incremental update?

Thank you for your help!